# Google reCaptcha on WP login page

Tags: login

Happy New Year!

Just wondering if anyone knows how can we user Google reCaptcha on WP login page?

Either v2 or v3

Comment: There are [existing plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/recaptcha/) to do that. I haven't used any to recommend them though.

Comment: Thank you - I will look it up

Answer (score 0):

Happy new year.

Here is plugin for this : https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-recaptcha/

Please check. i am sure you can get your requirements are fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

For a plugin, definitely consider [Login No Captcha reCAPTCHA by Robert Peake](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-recaptcha/).

If you're looking to roll something into your theme without introducing another plugin to the mix, Megan at Megabyte [created an article](https://megabyterose.com/2018/07/put-googles-invisible-recaptcha-on-wordpress-login-without-a-plugin/).

```php
<?php
/**
* These Functions Add and Verify the Invisible Google reCAPTCHA on Login
*/

add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'login_recaptcha_script');

function login_recaptcha_script() {
wp_register_script('recaptcha_login', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js');


wp_enqueue_script('recaptcha_login')


}



add_action( 'login_form', 'display_recaptcha_on_login' );

function display_recaptcha_on_login() {
echo "<script>
function onSubmit(token) {
document.getElementById('loginform').submit();
}
</script>
<button class='g-recaptcha' data-sitekey='YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY' data-callback='onSubmit' data-size='invisible' style='display:none;'>Submit</button>";


}



add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'verify_recaptcha_on_login', 10, 2);

function verify_recaptcha_on_login($user, $password) {

if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
$response = wp_remote_get( 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] );


$response = json_decode($response['body'], true);


if (true == $response['success']) {


return $user;


} else {


// FIXME: This one fires if your password is incorrect... Check if password was incorrect before returning this error...


// return new WP_Error( 'Captcha Invalid', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You are a bot') );


}


} else {


return new WP_Error( 'Captcha Invalid', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: You are a bot. If not then enable JavaScript.') );


}


}
```